# What is a recommended way to write MySQL queries neatly to improve readability?

Tags: php, mysql, readability, code-readability

For a while I always had my queries as one line:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = value ORDER BY id DESC
```

Now that I've been told multiple times not to use `*`, I've been trying to find a way to make longer queries readable. So far I have something like this:

```
SELECT table.id,
       table.type,
       table.name

FROM table

WHERE table.id > $lastId
AND table.type = $type

ORDER BY table.id ASC
```

This seems okay, but are there any best practices around that I should have a look at?

My MySQL stuff is done within the context of PHP.

Comment: if you are the only one viewing the code, its what is best for you.

Comment: the reason behind not blindly using `*` is not related to readability but you already knew that

Comment: Happy for this to be closed, though I am curious as to the existence of the [tag:code-readability] and similar tags if they're off-topic..

Comment: @MartyWallace people just want it to be sent to a better place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have it this way:

```
SELECT 
    t.id,               //indent fields to pick out
    t.type,
    t.name
FROM 
    table t             //shorter alias (but alias wisely)
WHERE 
    t.id > $lastId      //indent conditions
    AND t.type = $type
ORDER BY 
    t.id ASC            //indent order parameters
```

Comment: It is even better to always use "AS"  for aliases - it is syntactic sugar, but it aids readability.

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to what's readable for you, but it must be clear for other readers as well.

Personally, I do this:

```
SELECT 
    table.id,
    table.type,
    table.name
FROM table
WHERE table.id > $lastId
    AND table.type = $type
ORDER BY table.id ASC
```

Which is easily readable like your example is. In summary:

- Make your SQL readable so that other users of your code know what's going on, but;
- Use a style that you're personally comfortable with and like using.